# Install xml2json using older version of python

Tags: python, node.js

Very new to Python and Node.js
Trying to install xml2json on a windows 10 PC using the following

```
npm install xml2json -g
```

I get

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.EXE" is v3.5.1, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
```

Clear enough error message, so lets do this

```
npm install xml2json -g --python c:\Python\27\python.exe
npm ERR! not a package c:\Python\27\python.exe
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install c:\Python\27\python.exe
```

So that reads to me that we are now trying to install python and not xml2json.

I am sure this is just a really NewB mistake, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-gyp` accepts the --python flag, not npm. [According to the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp), you should run:

```
npm config set python "c:\Python\27\python.exe"
```

This command will save the python 2.7 path forever, then you can `npm install xml2json -g`.